# POST upload binary file with wininet in c++

Tags: c++, post, upload, binary, wininet

I have gotten this [Upload file via POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309661/upload-file-via-post) -example to work with .txt file. However I am still lacking a way to do the same with a binary file.

Could someone please show how to do that? I have gone over ~100 pages all over the internet of people asking this *VERY SAME* question... Many of those questions are on this site, but none have an answer that is any good. Codeproject has some ways but they seem to be based on MFC/ATL and I cant use those.

This question seems insanely difficult. :D So please, somebody, answer, pretty please. You would be doing me and quite many other people a favour. :)

Comment: Uploading binary is difficult from a browser… from C you just put the binary data after two newlines following the HTTP headers. The example you linked to has the `Content-Type` set to `image/jpeg` which is a binary format… what isn't working or you? Also, the `multipart/form-data` may be unnecessarily complicating things. What sort of service are you uploading to?

Comment: Do you control the server part? If not, what's the expected MIME type of the data - form or multipart? And what's so special about binary files as opposed to text ones - you're just not sure how to encode non-ASCII bytes?

Comment: Uploading through basic html form, like this http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php/ on a php platform. When I try uploading image, the with that script, the image goes through but the size of the image is only 4 bytes(iirc), so i think my problem is that i can't handle encoding non-ASCII bytes? :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any good example of http upload using WinInet c++ library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471198/is-there-any-good-example-of-http-upload-using-wininet-c-library)

Comment: Looks like guys sent raw data [with this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487990/6019417)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will upload the file: `1.jpg` to the specified host using `wininet` method and a simple http POST request

`(name=johndoe and document=1.jpg)`

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<wininet.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

DWORD rSize,filesize,bytesread,contentlen;

char tmp[2048]; //2Kb Response buffer
char szheaders[1024]; //1kb Header buffer
string chunks; //Server Response

HANDLE hfile;
HINTERNET hOpen2,hConnect2,hReq2;

char szstart[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla";
char szData[]    = "---------------------------acebdf13572468\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"firstname\"\r\n\r\njohndoe\r\n---------------------------acebdf13572468\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n";
char szDataEnd[] = "\r\n---------------------------acebdf13572468--\r\n";

int main()
{

    hfile=CreateFile("1.jpg",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

    if(hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

    wsprintf(szheaders,szData,"filetoupload","1.jpg");
    hOpen2=InternetOpen(TEXT("Mozilla/5.0"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(hOpen2){
        hConnect2=InternetConnect(hOpen2, TEXT("www.example.com"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, TEXT(""), TEXT(""), INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
        if(hConnect2){

           hReq2=HttpOpenRequest(hConnect2, TEXT("POST"), TEXT("/your_path/index.php"), TEXT("HTTP/1.1"),NULL,NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID |INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID, 0);
           if(hReq2){

                filesize=GetFileSize(hfile,NULL);
                contentlen=lstrlen(szheaders)+filesize+lstrlen(szDataEnd);

                LPBYTE pbuf=(LPBYTE)malloc(contentlen);
                CopyMemory(&pbuf[0],szheaders,lstrlen(szheaders));

                ReadFile(hfile,&pbuf[lstrlen(szheaders)],filesize,&bytesread,NULL);
                CopyMemory(&pbuf[lstrlen(szheaders)+filesize],szDataEnd,lstrlen(szDataEnd));

                BOOL status =  HttpSendRequest(hReq2,szstart,lstrlen(szstart),pbuf,contentlen);
                if (status){
                    chunks="";
                    while(InternetReadFile(hReq2, tmp, 2048, &rSize) && rSize > 0)
                    {
                        tmp[rSize] = '\0';
                        chunks += tmp;
                    }
                    cout << chunks;
                    //Prints Server response
                }
                    CloseHandle(hfile);
                    free(pbuf);
            } 
            InternetCloseHandle(hReq2);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hConnect2);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hOpen2);
    }

}
```

`g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -lwininet`